# Getting "No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands" error in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm relatively new to Azure DevOps. I have Azure DevOps Server 2019 installed on a Windows 2016 server. I created an Azure pipeline using the classic editor. I have four steps in my agent job which are: install node, 'npm install', 'dotnet restore', and 'ng test'. When I run the build I get the following error:

```
 No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands:
     Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.115.0
```

I looked at other StackOverflow posts and installed Visual Studio 2019 on the server to try to solve the problem. Still got the same error. Do I need to add something to the pipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either have Microsoft-hosted agents (provided by Microsoft to run jobs) or you can have Self-hosted agents (running on your own hardware or some VM).  When you configure to run against the Default pool, that would be the one setup for you to register any Self-Hosted agents.

If you navigate to agent pool for "Default" (Settings >> Agent Pools), I would guess you will see that Default doesn't have any configured agents.  You should probably walk through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) to download and register an agent for that pool.

From the Agent Pool screen for Default, there will also be a "New Agent" button you can press to get the download link with instructions.

Comment: You were right. I didn't have any agents configured. I downloaded the latest version of a Windows agent and got it configured DevOps. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So basically it tells that your agent version is not modern enough. [The doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=browser#agent-version-and-upgrades) says

> Starting with Azure DevOps Server 2019, you don't have to wait for a
> new server release. You can upload a new version of the agent to your
> application tier, and that version will be offered as an upgrade.

And the [next section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=browser#can-i-update-my-v2-agents-that-are-part-of-an-azure-devops-server-pool) provides info on upgrading. It's a matter of grabbing the newer version from [the Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases) and unpacking it to the `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Azure DevOps\Agents`.

Answer (score 1):

I've similar issue and I did fix it as below:

Simply, go to the agent pools >> under your pool >> select the agent >> click on the Three dots on the right >> update agent:

[image: Screenshot of my Issue]

Comment: It did not work