# ##[error]No agent found in pool which satisfies the following demand: BuildId. All demands: Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.182.1

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am trying to create VM's(6 vm's parallely) in Azure through AzureDevOps pipeline using azure cli and perform actions. But after creation of VM's it is taking longer time and finally failing with this error.
**##[error]No agent found in pool XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX which satisfies the following demand: BuildId. All demands: BuildId -equals XXXXX, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.182.1**

Can anyone route the exact route cause for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> **##[error]No agent found in pool XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX which satisfies the following demand: BuildId. All demands: BuildId -equals XXXXX, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.182.1**

The error shows that you don't have the agent while doing your task.
To fix this you can use the **Self-Hosted agent**. It gives you more control to **install dependent software** needed for your ***builds and deployments***.

Note: **Although multiple agents can be installed per machine, we strongly suggest to only install one agent per machine. Installing two or more agents may adversely affect performance and the result of your pipelines.**

Either you can use Microsoft-hosted agents or Self-Hosted Agents. If you configure run against the default pool, it would be one setup for you to register any Self-Hosted Agents.

1. Navigate to **Settings -> Agent pool** has **Default** and check whether it configures any agent or not. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) to download and register the agent for the pool.
2. Add new Agent for the Agent pool.  Click the **New Agent** button to download and use it.

#### Reference

- [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025319/getting-no-agent-found-in-pool-default-which-satisfies-the-specified-demands-e)
- [**Virtual Machine Scale Set Agents**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#azure-virtual-machine-scale-set-agents)